# Error creating bean with name 'customerRepository': Invocation of init method failed; No property updateCustomer found for type Customer

Tags: jpa, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

**CRUD operations using Spring Boot + JPA + Hibernate + PostgreSQL**

Please am new in this topic. Am trying to create a CRUD Api. Everything is ok but i cant get the UPDATE method using the JpaRepository. I dont have error when i  build my project.

I try to code a specific createCustomer method into my customerRepository but still not working
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmPXP.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Sxyc.png)

But when i run it with maven i get this error:

Comment: You should provide `@Query`. I suggest you read how spring data Repository methods work

Comment: yes ok  ... its oblige?  i have being working like this for the SAVE,  DELATE ... methodes

Comment: put code in the question, not in some arbitrarily linked images that may disappear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring data Repository work mostly with method names. It creates query based on the method name. For example in your Repository interface you have a method `findByUserId`. This will work even if you have not written any query. How ?
   spring-data will formulate the query to fetch the field specified after `findBy` (`UserId` in your case). But at compile time, it checks whether you are providing a valid field So that it can prepare a proper query. It does so by checking your entity class (`Customer` in your case) for this field.

**Note :** keep in mind that field in Entity is called `userId` but method name in Repository is called `UserId`.

The reason save, delete methods are working because you are extending JPARepository class(which in-turn extends other classes), which has these methods. So it works out of the box.

But when you write some method which is not there in any of the super class, then spring-data will try to formulate the query on its own as I specified earlier. So when you write a method like `updateCustomer`  which is not in any of the super classes, then it tries to find in the entity class a field with name updateCustomer and it fails since it cannot find and hence the exception.

So if you want to declare or do something like this, you can do this by annotating such method with `@Query(....)` and providing the right query inside it.

```
@Query(update customer set ..........)  
Customer updateCustomer(Customer customer)
```

Hope its clear.

Comment: OK. Thanks so much. Its clear for me. Let me do it and i will be back with results.

Comment: So basically all methods have to be capitalized